# Python: Returning a function that runs a given function n times

Tags: python, function, closures, decorator

I'm trying to write a function that takes a function as its argument and returns a new function that runs said function a given number of times.

For example, if I had a function:

```
def doubleNumber(num):
    return num * 2
```

and I did the following:

```
doubleThrice = repeatFunction(doubleNumber, 3)
```

I should then get this:

```
doubleThrice(3) # Returns 18 but should it?
```

I have this so far, but I don't think it's doing what I want:

```
def repeatFunction(func, n):
    def inner(inp):
        return func(inp) * n
    return inner
```

I get the impression that it is just running the function once and then multiplying the result by n, not running the function n times, though I'm not sure.

I just can't think of how to build the function I need inside the repeatFunction function and return it, nor has any of the online help really made sense to me.

Comment: doubleThrice(3) returns 18 in your example.

Comment: Sorry why is this being voted down? I've provided what looks like a reasonable example for a question that I'm sure others have worried about before also. Seems impossible to ask a good question around here.

Comment: @dot.Py Does it? I'm really not sure what my given function does in this circumstance, it's just what I've got so far. Was looking for some guidance on how best to do what I've described :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to apply a function several times, you probably need a loop that repeats that many times:

```
def repeatFunction(func, n):
    def inner(inp):
        for i in range(n):
            inp = func(inp)
        return inp
    return inner
```

Comment: Yes! This is exactly what I needed, could've sworn I tried this already... Makes perfect sense to just keep compounding the answer with repeated function calls. Surely the most straightforward answer, will mark it as such as soon as I can. Thanks!